# ESLint error in VSCode - Parsing error: '?' expected

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Here's the code in question:

```
type Params<T> = { 
  [K in keyof Nested<T>]: 
    (Parameters<
      Nested<T>[K] extends infer U extends (...args: any) => any ? U : never
    >) 
};
```

The error is on the `U` of `infer U`:

```
Parsing error: '?' expected.
```

The type seems to be inferred correctly, so I don't think it's a TS error. How to get VSCode to see it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to add an `extends` constraint to an `infer`ed type variable:

```
type Params<T> = { 
  [K in keyof Nested<T>]: 
    (Parameters<
      Nested<T>[K] extends infer U extends (...args: any) => any ? U : never
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                    `extends` constraint on `infer`ed type variable
    >) 
};
```

The ability to do this was only introduced in TypeScript 4.7 ([reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables)). You can verify it works in a TypeScript Playground configured to use TypeScript 4.7 [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJyzDm). And you can see a reproduction of your issue in a TypeScript Playground configured to use TypeScript 4.6 [here](https://tsplay.dev/wjnG7w).

If compilation works but VS Code is erroring, your project and VS Code may have been configured to use different versions of TypeScript. See VS Code's documentation on the [compiler vs language service](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_compiler-versus-language-service).

Comment: Here is an alternative for version <4.7 https://tsplay.dev/wep1gW